# Powershell doesn't recognise (default) registry as string in comparison

Tags: string, powershell, compare, registry

When I try to use the comparison operator when reading the registry, the (default) keys don't seem to compare correctly. The default keys are string, but when I compare to string, it doesn't match:

First, example registry created:

- hkcu:\branch1\branch2
- hkcu:\branch1\branch2 ! (default) = defaultValue  (REG_SZ)
- hkcu:\branch1\branch2 ! testVal1  = testValue     (REG_SZ)

If we then run the following command:

```
(gp HKCU:\branch1\branch2).PSObject.Properties | ? {$_.Name -notlike 'PS*'} | select Name, TypeNameOfValue, Value | ft -a
```

Result:

> Name      TypeNameOfValue Value
>
> ----      --------------- -----
>
> (default) System.String   defaultValue
>
> testVal1  System.String   testValue

As you can see, it clearly lists the default value as a String. So, why does the following comparison NOT work?

```
Get-ItemProperty "HKCU:\branch1\branch2" | ForEach-Object { 
    $CurrentKey = $_
    write-host "Looking at key $CurrentKey"
    foreach ($PropertyName in ($CurrentKey | Get-Item).GetValueNames()) {
    if ($CurrentKey.$PropertyName -is [string]) {
        write-host $PropertyName with value of $CurrentKey.$PropertyName STRING!
    }
    else{               
        write-host $PropertyName with value of $CurrentKey.$PropertyName NOT STRING!                            
    }
}
```

}

Which gives the result:

> Looking at key @{(default)=defaultValue; testVal1=testValue}
>
> with value of NOT STRING!
>
> testVal1 with value of testValue STRING!

You will see the (default) value output is blank (both the name and the value) and is not detected as a string. Why is this? Why can't I compare the default value to a STRING?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a test key with the teststring value. This how I compared the TypeName of the value :

```
$test = (gp HKCU:\test\).PSObject.Properties

if (($test.Item("teststring").TypeNameOfValue) -eq "System.String") {"yes"} else {"no"}
```

Comment: Whilst the following works: `if (($test.Item("(default)").TypeNameOfValue) -eq "System.String")` I'm having trouble getting the "default" name as a variable. Since I'm looping through the registry with the code posted, the name default value NAME is being returned as "blank" rather than "(default)" in the variable.

Comment: Just checked the foreach loop in my example and it returned with the (default) name, and the system.string value type. `foreach ($row in $test) {Write-Host $row.Name, $row.TypeNameOfValue}`

Comment: (edit)I did it this way - added: `if ($PropertyName -eq ""){$valName="(default)"}else{$valName=$PropertyName}` to the code, then run with `if (($test.Item($valName).TypeNameOfValue) -eq "System.String"` This is working for me.  However, your code looks nicer - I'll see if I can update the loop code. Thanks

Comment: There is a problem with your foreach loop. If you modify based on my prev comment it should work I believe.

Comment: My loop returns a value name for each value of any type, except for default. It might relate to how default is handled (i.e. if you export to a text file, the name is simply "@" rather than "(default)". In any case, your code is better and more elegant IMO.